# ls command ignore specific directory [bash]

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ls

Tree:

```
a.txt (file)
Tests/b.txt (directory)
c.txt (file)
```

ls :

```
a.txt
Tests/b.txt
c.txt
```

Ignore specific file:

ls -I c.txt :

```
a.txt
Tests/b.txt
```

Ignore specific directory:

ls -I Tests : (does not work - Tests directory should not appear)

```
a.txt
Tests/b.txt
c.txt
```

Comment: What is your question? The behaviour you describe - is it what you want or what you don't want? The reason I ask is that little of your sample output makes sense, nor does it match what the real `/bin/ls` actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "man page" for the `ls` command explains that the `-I` flag accepts a *pattern*. So you can use a wildcard in your command:

```
ls -I Tests*
```

See: `man ls` or the commands [online man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)

Comment: With wildcard is quoting important.

Comment: @Cyrus: Is that a question?

Comment: That was no question.

Comment: @Cyrus Then maybe you want to explain what you mean by it, so that we mere mortals can understand...